# Mono Control Drawing?

Tags: mono

I was wondering how Mono draws its controls ? I'm thinking of using it for a cross platform program but I can't find any comparisons of what it looks like on each platform (the lack of media on their official website is also concerning). I may also want to create my own controls with my own drawing functions so I was wondering if it does something like Qt in that it handles all it's own drawing so it looks the same across platforms.

Answer (score 0):

All Mono Winforms control drawing is done by Mono in C# using System.Drawing.  Controls look like Win32 classic on all platforms.

Some screenshots are available on the screenshots page:

http://mono-project.com/Screenshots

Note you'll want to scroll down for Winforms.